# Add nodes in openshift origin

Tags: openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I am running openshift origin All-in-One setup using available binaries. Is it possible to add multiple nodes to this existing installation ?

What are the prerequisites for this, do I need to setup ssh connections between hosts?

Please do let me know how or if there is any link available for the same?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add additional nodes. [Check this link](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/master_node_configuration.html)
Basically you have to export the config for this new node and move it over to that node and start using the node-config.yaml

Comment: Hey, thanks ,You mean manually create  "node-config.yaml " for additional node, but how to start server using multiple node-config files? I already have origin installation with one master and one node.Here I start my origin server using "openshift start --master-config=openshift.local.config/master/master-config.yaml --node-config=openshift.local.config/node1/node-config.yaml"                               what to do in case of multiple nodes?

Comment: From the same link I gave above - To launch a node server using a node configuration file:

$ openshift start node --config=/openshift.local.config/node-<node_hostname>/node-config.yaml

Comment: hey , but is it possible to run openshift using "openshift start" with two node configs? as in my previous comment. Thanks for help

Comment: Why will you start 2 nodes on the same server ? I guess I may not be understanding your requirement. The assumption is that you have already started all in one server that has master and node running on say server A . Now you have to start another node on Server B. So you login to B bring the node config tar and start node on B using "openshift start node.."

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying, but how master will connect to  node on server B then? what if I need to create apps on node B from master running in server A inside all in one mode? master and nodes should be connected to each other right? Would be very helpful if you can clarify this too? thankyou so much!